# How to choose the best one model from ARIMAX, ARCH/GARCH and VAR?

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection, garch, vector-autoregression

Now I have 3 models to find what economic factors have an effect on gold price:

1. ARIMAX model
2. ARCH/GARCH model
3. VAR model

What is the tool to find the best model? In linear regression, we can calculate goodness-of-fit to decide what is the best one but in a time series model what is the tool to find that?

Comment: Can you check the PRESS statistic or evaluate with kfold Cross-Validation?

Comment: Kfold is suitfor identifying factors influencing a dependent variable when forecasting isn't the primary goal? Could you explain more.

Comment: You should always consider measuring the goodness of a model in an end-to-end fashion. This means you should be able to have one or more KPIs for the performance of your model. Log-likelihood based metrics may be a performance measure but some business cases are better evaluated by cost sensitive machine learning ... That said you need to know what aspects you're interested in

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at forecast accuracy / cross validation. By testing the model on part of the dataset that was not used to fit the model. In other settings such as multivariable regression, it is common to split the data randomly. With time series this obviously won't work, and instead a sequential approach is needed such as a *rolling window* which involves training the model on a fixed-size segment of the data and forecasting the next point. The window then rolls forward by one observation, and the process repeats. Another approach is an *expanding window* which is similar but the training set expands to include all data up to the current point in each iteration.

You can also look at metrics such as AIC/BIC and Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE).

Comment: I'm understanding that RMSE is often used for model selection in forecasting, but I'm uncertain if it's the best choice for identifying factors influencing a dependent variable when forecasting isn't the primary goal. Could you clarify its suitability in this context?